# Splitting A String In Two Parts(REALBASIC)

Tags: realbasic, realstudio

I am trying to split a string at the character ":" but cant create two separate strings from the split. If somebody could help me, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

In RealBasic, the [Split](http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/Split) method doesn't create two (or more) separate strings but rather a single string [array](http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/Arrays_and_String_Processing_Algorithms).

```vb
Dim s() As String = Split("Zero:One:Two", ":")
's() now contains the substrings like so:
's(0) = "Zero"
's(1) = "One"
's(2) = "Two"
```

Comment: Thanks! I was having trouble learning RB from Java. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the code is incorrect.  It should be:

```
Dim s() As String = Split("Zero:One:Two", ":")
```

If you don't pass in the delimiter it assumes a space which wouldn't work in this case.

The online docs are at http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/Split

Answer (score 0):

Split is best for actually splitting the text, but you can also use the string-manipulation methods: Left, Right, Mid and InStr.